# cxf failover recovery

Tags: apache, jax-ws, cxf, failover

I have a cxf JAX-WS client. I added the failover strategy. The question is how the client can recovery from the backup solution and use again the primary URL? Because now after the client will switch to secondary URL remains there, will not use the primary URL even if this become available again.

The code for the client part is:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(GatewayPort.class);
factory.setAddress(this.configFile.getPrimaryURL());

FailoverFeature feature = new FailoverFeature();
SequentialStrategy strategy = new SequentialStrategy();
List<String> addList = new ArrayList<String>();
addList.add(this.configFile.getSecondaryURL());
strategy.setAlternateAddresses(addList);
feature.setStrategy(strategy);

List<AbstractFeature> features = new ArrayList<AbstractFeature>();
features.add(feature);
factory.setFeatures(features);

this.serviceSoap = (GatewayPort)factory.create();

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(this.serviceSoap);
if (client != null)
{
    HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit)client.getConduit();
    HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    policy.setConnectionTimeout(this.configFile.getTimeout());
    policy.setReceiveTimeout(this.configFile.getTimeout());
    conduit.setClient(policy);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add the primary URL to the alternate addresses list instead of setting that to JaxWsProxyFactoryBean. This way, since you are using SequentialStrategy, the primary URL will be checked first for every service call, if it fails then secodary URL will be tried.

Comment: At the end was choose other approach: custom mechanism to send data to secondary URL. Something like: try 2 times to send to first URL if fails send to second URL. (Added this approach because of business model changes on new info from the URLs provider)

Answer (score 0):

You might as well try an alternative CXF failover feture with failback.

https://github.com/jaceko/cxf-circuit-switcher